# jq: where select clause is applied

Tags: jq

Here my documents:

```json
[
   {
      "id":"f3b8c257-9950-45e7-9e79-ace19ec8905e",
      "identifier":[
         {
            "system":{
               "value":"urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.10.2"
            },
            "value":{
               "value":"10839812"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"f0a1e3ae-826f-4a03-b29e-10ef3bc86ea0",
      "identifier":null
   }
]
```

Currently, I'm aplying this jq filter:

```
map(
    {
        id,
        dni: .identifier[] | (select(.system.value == "urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.19126.3") | .value.value)
    }
)
```

However, I'm getting this message:

> jq: error (at practitioner-mongoexport.json:146715): Cannot iterate over null (null)

As you can guess, problem arises processing second object where `.identifier: null`.

I've tried with that:

```
map(
    {
        id,
        dni: select(.identifier) | .identifier[] | (select(.system.value == "urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.19126.3") | .value.value)
    }
)
```

I've also tried with:

```
map(
    select(.identifier) |
    {
        id,
        dni: .identifier[] | (select(.system.value == "urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.19126.3") | .value.value)
    }
)
```

Then result is `[]`.

I don't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My desired output would be:

```json
[
   {
      "id":"f3b8c257-9950-45e7-9e79-ace19ec8905e",
      "dni": "10839812"
   }
]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: The .system.vakue in your select does not exist in the input json\

Comment: I've edited post with desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deal with the case if `.identifier` is `null`. Here, the `?` operator may help.

- without selection

```sh
jq 'map({id, dni: (.identifier[]?).value.value})'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/32DHYOH5eM)

- with selection

```sh
jq 'map({id, dni: (.identifier[]? | select(.system.value == "urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.10.2")).value.value})'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/VnOwRKUAuM)

```json
[
  {
    "id": "f3b8c257-9950-45e7-9e79-ace19ec8905e",
    "dni": "10839812"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
map(
    select(.identifier?[]?.system.value == "urn:oid:2.16.724.4.9.10.2") 
    | { id, "dni": .identifier[].value.value }
)
```

Will generate:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "f3b8c257-9950-45e7-9e79-ace19ec8905e",
    "dni": "10839812"
  }
]
```

---

The trick here is `.identifier?[]?.system.value` where the `?` will ignore `.identifier` if it's `null`

---

##### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/BfFzE-1gbk)

Comment: I don't find the first `?` in `.identifier?[]?.system.value` to make any difference.